# Why would it be bad practice to limit current with just a resistor?

Tags: led, current, resistance

I am sure I am incorrect, but nobody can tell me why I am incorrect.

I have some LEDs that require 1amp. My DC source 52v @ 2.6amp  [DC power source](http://HLG-120H-54A%20AC/DC%20Power%20Supply%20Single-OUT%2054V)  (constant current technology)

A proper solution is not easy without careful engineering. All ICs on mouser get close but still leave to much amp. Restricting proper amps for high powered LEDs is important.

I want to just slap on a few resistors behind  [current regulator (updated)](https://www.allegromicro.com/~/media/Files/Datasheets/ALT80800-Datasheet.ashx) ALT80800KLPATR (and not part of topology, yet, if at all), and call it a day.
wishlist: It would get the voltage down, regulate the current and leave some play room for an Arduino to switch resistor values for a possible LED upgrade (what if I need an extra amp later?).

I am told I am wrong which I am sure I am but, when they say it can't be done I show them  [image: before additional 560ohm resistor]  then after adding a 560 ohm  [image: after adding 560ohm resistor]

If I am wrong, then I am wrong but those numbers tell me that it should do what I want it to do.

Can somebody debunk me properly?

Comment: First of all, your measurement seems incorrect. It feels highly unlikely that your LED would light with 0.09mA. Secondly, your supply clearly isnt constant current if putting a resistor in series is decreasing the current. From your pictures, it's not clear how you're connecting the LED and resistor with the multimeter, can you add a schematic?

Comment: In addition to what @BeB00 said we need a link to the datasheet or specs for your DC source.

Comment: @JohnD I updated the post with that info

Comment: @BeB00 I added datasheets. The images are just proof of concept. Yes, those readings are real. No schematic has been done yet.

Comment: Show a schematic.  Without that we can't tell what you have hooked up to what, and what exactly the meter is measuring.  No, those pictures aren't proof of anything you say since we don't know what we're looking, where the wires go, what is connected to what, etc.  Again, show a schematic is required here.

Comment: Draw a schematic! Your first link is broken. Your second link is not to a current regulator but to an electronic fuse. -1

Comment: *Why would it be bad practice to limit current with just a resistor?* That would either be an excellent idea (LED powered from some DC source) or a bad idea (LED on very high voltage like mains voltage, high power LED powered by a fixed current driver). **It depends on the circumstances**. Your setup is unclear (no schematic) so I'm moving on...

Comment: I can't draw it any cleaner than the posted images and KiCAD is screwing up. The ONLY difference is 54v (on CC tech) vs 5.5v

Comment: anything else we are just grabbing from thin air.

Comment: The LED shown on the picture definitely is not a 1A diode. I also do not see any constant current circuit, just resistors, and a supply.  So what was the point of this experiment?

Comment: because it is ANY arbitrary high voltage to match ANY arbitrary 1 amp circuit. The LED is just a sample. Constant current means nothing because I intend on unconstanting it. Any resistor combination is available to make the math work.

Comment: ALT80800 regulator that you've linked to already gives you ability to adjust output current by adjusting sensor resistor. You don't need anything else. And you definitely don't have to "unconstanting" it, because then you don't need it at all.

Comment: Putting a resistor in series with a constant current supply won't reduce the current until the load resistance is so high that the powersupply can't raise the voltage high enough to push the required current.

Comment: [What you need is the correct driver. These guys make a lot of ones with different output currents.](https://www.meanwellaustralia.com.au/products/hbg-100p) The linked powersupply is 2A, but is adjustable.

Comment: @JRE Is that why OHMs law says a 5ohm resistor would regulate the voltage by 1 amp on a 5v circuit but in practice it takes a 560 ohm resistor to regulate it .1amps???

Comment: @JRE Thats really all I want to do is give it a cap. Just as you state.  I am looking at the device you posted right now. Thank you!

Comment: Yep.  The constant current power supply tries to force its set current through the load.  It jacks up the voltage to try and make that hapoen.  So, you put in a 100 ohm resistor, it jacks up the voltage to keep the current flowing. More resistance, more voltage.  Then the power supply hits its upper voltage limit, and can't maintain the current any more.

Comment: @BeB00 The brightness depends on the LED efficiency, but you can definitely tell when a LED is on at 0.02mA to 0.10mA. Not bright, but on.

Comment: @JRE Thank you for clarifying why they said I am an idiot. I see the potential error now. My example above was referring to what happens without constant current.

Comment: @JRE my REAL topology will be 54v CC -> 54v Quantum Board -> the above proposed circuit (with Cree LEDs instead, is all). That QBoard should mask forced changes in AMPs at the tail end of the circuit. It should just appear to the CC device and a little extra current draw, which it is. The layers of diodes between the new LED circuit and the CC device should be ok. If not, I know exactly why now.

Comment: @Maple the ALT80800 delivers 2 amps. 1 amp too many. Thats the ONLY drawback. None go from all the way up at 54v down to 1 amp. but this is not bad if I want to implement an Arduino for an optional 2nd circuit. One with the resistor regulation, the other bare.

Comment: ALT80800 is **rated** for 2 A maximum. Read the manual! "Output current is user-selectable by an external current sense
resistor." If you bypass current regulation by adding resistors in series you will dissipate a **lot of heat** on those resistors. It just doesn't make any sense. You can remove regulator and connect LEDs with resistors to any constant voltage source for exactly same effect.

Comment: @boobie Sorry, I have to delete my answer. I am tired of explaining people that I am not suggesting calculating LED current using Ohm's law. Can you un-accept it? I cannot delete it otherwise

Comment: @Map: Huh? Delete *what* exactly.  I wrote a single comment, which is the only thing I can delete.

Comment: @Boob: You were told 20 hours ago that a schematic was required.  I can see from your profile that you were back here 14 hours ago, but still no schematic.  My patience has expired.  Have a -1 now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to know where to begin with a question like this. It seems that there are many things you don't fully understand about electricity and LED's. I will do my best.

What determines the brightness of an LED is how much current goes through it. So when driving an LED, the goal is always to achieve the desired current. The starting point for design is always based on two things:

1. How much current does the LED need?
2. What will be the voltage across the LED when that much current is flowing?

There are lots of ways to drive LED's. One of the most common for low power indicator LED's in low-voltage circuits is to have a voltage source supply current to a resistor/LED. We call the resistor a "current-limiting resistor" because its purpose is to limit the current to a chosen value. Here:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fj0O9r.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The LED current will be (3.3-Vf) / 560

Vf is the forward voltage across the LED. "Forward" just means in the direction required to turn the LED on.

This works fine as long as you are OK with the power dissipated by R1. If V1 was 100V, for example, then R1 would need to be a large and cumbersome power resistor, and you might need to add a fan or heatsink to keep things cool.

Another way is to use some type of current source. In that case, it is pointless to add a resistor. All the resistor will do is dissipate power without changing the LED current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmC1NJ.png)</sup>

But this is not the last word. Because REAL current sources only work over some finite output voltage range. If you add a big resistor in series with a real current source, at some point, it will typically act like a voltage source. At that point, you may be able to limit current with a resistor (just like the first circuit). That could be what is happening for you. Not sure.

Some current sources may not like it if you put a large resistor in series. So if you are not sure it is best to avoid doing that. You might get unreliable behavior or unpredictable results. You can also try dimming your LED by adding a resistor in parallel with the LED. This also wastes power, but should not cause harm to the supply or the LED.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fD1H2v.png)</sup>

Basically, what you are doing is giving the current an alternate route so that not all the current flows through the LED. The smaller the resistor, the less current flows through the LED. The exact current through the resistor will be Vf/R1.

In all cases with resistors, you should calculate the power dissipation in the resistor to make sure it is reasonable. I would say reasonable is up to around 100 mW. From 100mW to 500mW might be OK in some cases. Above 500mW, you should figure out a more efficient way to drive or dim the LED, because getting rid of 500mW without overheating other stuff is going to be more trouble than designing a more efficient circuit to begin with.

Comment: You can get very high efficiency for high power and or high voltage LEDs using a current limiting resistor.  Especially if the supply voltage is adjustable.

Comment: @Misunderstood, when using a current limiting resistor, efficiency is basically Vf/Vsupply. I didn't mean to suggest otherwise.

Comment: @mkeith Thank you for your beautiful response. You added a lot of clarity. Other than the CC technology, there is nothing wrong with my proposal, its just ugly/dirty/wasteful. but perfectly valid. "typically act like a voltage source" i think is valid in my case.

Comment: Yes, but there could be current output regulators out there that are not well-behaved when driving large resistors, or that may shut down due to over-voltage if they are unable to achieve target output current. Just keep that in mind if you switch to a different LED driver.

Answer (score 0):

The ALT80800KLPATR may be overkill for your application. You could light up a large room very brightly with that kind of power.

> but nobody can tell me why I am incorrect.

You are wrong, adding a series resistor to a constant current source will not change the amount of current flowing.

---

> there is nothing wrong with my proposal, its just ugly/dirty/wasteful.
>   but perfectly valid.

No not valid.  You do not understand basic DC fundamentals well enough to understand when you are being told you are wrong.  Here is where @mkeith told you you were wrong:

> it is pointless to add a resistor. All the resistor will do is
>   dissipate power without changing the LED current
> - mkeith

---

> I am told I am wrong which I am sure I am but, when they say it can't
>   be done I show them

It can be done, maybe not by you, first you need to understand basic fundamentals of electricity.

---

> If I am wrong, then I am wrong but those numbers tell me that it
>   should do what I want it to do.

You could do without with the ALT80800KLPATR and use a resistor, but that would be very inefficient for powering a single LED with 52V.  You could fairly efficiently power a non-dimmable string of 16 (or so depending on forward voltage) LEDs with 52V with a single resistor.

For a single LED you want to drop the voltage to about 0.1V over the maximum forward voltage of the LED(s) at maximum current.  Then use a current limiting resistor to set the maximum current.  You can then use the Enable pin on the step down regulator as the PWM dimmer.

You will need a high voltage drop down regulator with an enable pin
(e.g.[Texas Instruments LM46002 60V Simple Switcher Step Down Regulator](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm46002.pdf) )
The LM46002 would be about 89% efficient at 1 Amp 3.3V output.

[image]

---

### Example Resistor Values with 1 Amp V<sub>f</sub> = 3.0V

#### Single LED 96.77% Efficient

[image]

---

#### String of 10 LEDs, 99.67% Efficient

[image]

---

> The ONLY difference is 54v (on CC tech) vs 5.5v

With the ALT80800KLPATR the output voltage is a function of the LED's forward voltage.  The 5.5V VCCout is a 14 mA max used to power something like a  thermal foldback circuit.

Comment: I don't think it is a good practice to have only 0.1V across your current limiting resistor. A slight variation in LED forward voltage (for example due to temperature change) will lead to a relatively large change in forward current. For better control of forward current, the voltage across the current limiting resistor should be around 10% of the LED Vf at the desired operating point. This will still give you 90% efficiency.

Comment: I did say at maximum current and now added maximum to the forward voltage so it reads: " to about 0.1V over the maximum forward voltage of the LED(s) at maximum current."   The manufactures already add 10%.   Typical Vf = 2.75 max = 3V.  I find that the actual measured Vf is below what is spec'd in the datasheet.  If it is a hobby project I'm willing to take that risk.  When it's a commercial product, I'm not likely to take any risk that creates a field service call.